# I cant use swipe with fancybox and jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I was hopping if anyone came to such problem with fancybox and swipe.

By visiting directly this page : https://knk.vpn.gr/copy/about/#.filter-cat202-4 i have a fancybox fired with a video and some images.

Swipe left and right isnt working and cant figure out why.
I dont have any console errors.

The code i'm using for the fancybox is:

```js
$.fancybox.open($(".grid__link__fancy"), {
  fullScreen: {
    autoStart: false
  },
  infobar: false,
  buttons: ["slideShow", "close"],
  protect: true,
  clickContent: function(current, event) {
    return current.type === "image" ? "false" : false;
  },
  transitionEffect: "fade",
  transitionDuration: 2000,
  animationDuration: 1000,
  clickSlide: "false",
  slideShow: {
    autoStart: true,
    speed: 1000
  },
  beforeClose: function() {
    project_fancybox_close();
  },
  afterClose: function() {

  },
});
```

is there something i could check or change to make it work? I read that swipe is enabled by default.
I'm using fancybox v3.5.7 with jquery 3.5.7

best,

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @biberman Oviously not, because that question was about Fanybox v2, this question is about v3, but the latest is v4.

Comment: You're right - my fault. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Fancybox works and has been working fine for years. Swipe guestures work perfectly fine, too, and there are no extra steps required to enable them, because they are enabled by default.

So, the issue is with your site. You didn't mention in your post that your page is a very heavy WordPress page that uses a number of other scripts. You use Elementor, GSAP and god knows what else. To tell you exactly what's wrong with your page, I may have to spend an entire day debugging your site. Sorry, but SO is not about asking others to do that.

A possible solution would be to upgrade to Fancybox v4, as there are significant improvements.